# not able to read fiile GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("E:\\client_secret.json");

Tags: java, gmail-api

I am using the source code that I got from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java
When I am running this in eclipse I am getting error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at googleemailid.GmailQuickstart.authorize(GmailQuickstart.java:79)
    at googleemailid.GmailQuickstart.getGmailService(GmailQuickstart.java:101)
    at googleemailid.GmailQuickstart.main(GmailQuickstart.java:109)

InputStream in =GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("E:\\client_secret.json");

    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Error comes at 
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

For debugging I tried to read the file using the InputStream and its able to read the file and file is present with full permission.  Also I got following warning.

```
Jun 08, 2015 5:45:43 AM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\Abc\.credentials\gmail-api-quickstart
Jun 08, 2015 5:45:43 AM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\Abc\.credentials\gmail-api-quickstart
```

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` is used to access the resources that are shipped with your application (inside the jar/war, etc). That's not your case, so access the file with `FileInputStream`.

Comment: your suggestion worked.  Now I am getting

Comment: Now I am getting error      at   Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
 at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:98) 
although its a command line application